# What is this disease on my peach leaf?

Tags: fruit-trees, diseases, peaches

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the problem/disease that causes bobbly peach tree leaves?](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/3092/what-is-the-problem-disease-that-causes-bobbly-peach-tree-leaves)

As I was spraying my peaches, I found this ugly pink puffing on my peach leaves. What is it and how do I get rid of it?[image: the upper surface][image: underside]

Comment: See this answer to the same question: http://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/3092/what-is-the-problem-disease-that-causes-bobbly-peach-tree-leaves It is almost certainly peach leaf curl and is combated when the parasites migrate to or from the leaves in early spring and late autumn.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like [peach leaf curl](http://byf.unl.edu/peach-leaf-curl). As far as I know it is not curable, but it is preventable (for next year) -- quoting from that UNL page:

> Fortunately, peach leaf curl is one of the easiest fruit diseases to control. In most years, leaf curl can be effectively prevented with a single application of an appropriate fungicide, including lime sulfur, chlorothalonil, Bordeaux mixture, or a copper fungicide.

You should spray in late winter.